# C# Mysql insert query "Data truncated for column costs"

Tags: c#, mysql

I am working on application that manipulates with MySQL database but i have error when inserting values in this table:

```
private const string createItemTableQuery = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `virtualstartupdb`.`item` (" +
                                "`id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT," +
                                "`name` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL," +
                                "`title` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL," +
                                "`description` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL," +
                                "`language_id` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL," +
                                "`price` DOUBLE(12,2) NOT NULL," +
                                "`costs` DOUBLE(12,2) NOT NULL," +
                                "`item_type_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL," +
                                "PRIMARY KEY(`id`)," +
                                "FOREIGN KEY(item_type_id) REFERENCES `virtualstartupdb`.`item_type` (id) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION); ";
```

I also have class for inserting queries in that table:

these are attributes:

```
long _id;
double _costs;
string _name;
string _title;
string _description;
string _language_id;
double _price;
long _item_type_id;
```

this is insert query I am using:

```
private string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `virtualstartupdb`.`item` (`name`, `title`, `description`, `language_id`, `price`, `item_type_id`, `costs`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', '{4}', '{5}', '{6}');";
```

It is all OK when I insert values like 2650, 551, 0 for attributes costs and price, but when I try to insert 41.67 or 193.33 I get this error on console:

```
Error in adding mysql row. Error: Data truncated for column 'costs' at row 1
```

I also tried with float, same error. What I am doing wrong ?

Comment: A value of `193.33` shouldn't raise this error.

Comment: 41.67 and 193.33 sounds like they might actually have been inserted with infinite decimals (like 41.6666666666667 or 193.333333333). Are you sure your values really are only 2 decimals? And also, consider using DECIMAL fields instead to not loose precision.

Comment: I don't think thats the case. I even tried Math.round(costs, 2) before inserting, still same error.

Comment: I will try with DECIMAL

Comment: Gah! The sql injection vulnerability. It burns us!

Answer (score 1):

Per your posted table definition `costs DOUBLE(12,2) NOT NULL` costs column can hold a value upto 12 digits long out of which 2 digits can be after decimal point and that's what `DOUBLE(M,D)` states for.

With that a value of `193.33` is perfectly right and shouldn't cause any issue at all. You must debug your code by placing a break point and see which particular values are causing this error / exception.

Wrap your code in a `try .. catch` block.
Again, instead of having the entire `CREATE` statement in a string; offload that to a stored procedure and call that procedure from your code behind rather.

Answer (score 1):

Requests that you use DECIMAL are correct. You should almost always use DECIMAL instead of DOUBLE when working with money. But I don't think that's really the problem here. It's important to make the change, but when it's done I'll be you still get the same error.

Instead, I suspect the problem has to do with the single quotes around your placeholders for the `costs` and `price` fields. This makes MySQL first cast your value to a string, which must then be cast back to `DOUBLE(12,2)` to match the column type. Somewhere in that double conversion you're losing precision and end up with a floating point rounding error that gives you more decimal places than you think you should have.

Alternatively, your server is running with a default local that uses `,` instead of `.` for the decimal separator.

Additionally, this technique is crazy vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You can solve all three problems (casting, decimal separator, and massive security hole) by using parameterized queries:

```
private string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `virtualstartupdb`.`item` (`name`, `title`, `description`, `language_id`, `price`, `item_type_id`, `costs`) VALUES ( @name, @title, @description, @language_id, @price, @item_type_id, @costs );";
private string connectionString = "Connection String here";

public void InsertRecord(MyInsertType newData)
{
    using (var cn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(insertQuery, cn))
    {
        //Guessing at column types and lengths here
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = newData._name;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = newData._title;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@description", MySqlDbType.VarString, 1000).Value = newData._description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@language_id", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 5).Value = newData._language_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@price", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newData._price;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@item_type_id", MySqlDbType.Int64).Value = newData._item_type_id;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@costs", MySqlDbType.Decimal).Value = newData._costs;

        cn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the quotation marks off the numeric values in your INSERT.

```
  private string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `virtualstartupdb`.`item` (`name`, `title`, `description`, `language_id`, `price`, `item_type_id`, `costs`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', {4}, {5}, {6});";
```

When you leave the quotation marks in place you're making MySQL do a string-to-numeric conversion.

Better yet, use a parameterized query. You can read about that.

Comment: Umm, but that conversion won't cause this. Would it?

Comment: I tried but now I get different error: Error in adding mysql row. Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I think problem is that it is somehow formatting my decimal numbers like 197,33 and not 197.33

Comment: "Better yet, use a parameterized query" - if you only do one thing, do this.

Answer (score -5):

Thank you all for your answers, but I found out that somehow mySQL is accepting my values with commas, not dots (193.33 is 193,33 etc.). So i changed my query to this:

```
private string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO `virtualstartupdb`.`item` (`name`, `title`, `description`, `language_id`, `price`, `item_type_id`, `costs`) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}', REPLACE('{4}', ',', '.'), {5}, REPLACE('{6}', ',', '.'));";
```

Now everything works like charm!

Comment: Until someone puts a single quote in the description field.